# Clear all form fields at once, reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

I want to clear all fields on click of reset button in the form. How can I 
  do it using state? I am using material ui theme. I dont want to set states 
   individually. Is that possible?

```
 <form className={classes.form}>
      <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="Name">Name</InputLabel>
        <Input id="name" name="name" autoComplete="name" autoFocus />
      </FormControl>
      <div className ='switchdesign'>
       <FormControlLabel   required 
          label="Private ? "
          labelPlacement="start"
              control={
                <Switch
                  checked={this.state.checkedA}
                  onChange={this.handleChange('checkedA')}
                  value="checkedA" />
              } />
        </div>
      <div className ='switchdesign'>
          <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
      <Select
        labelPlacement="start"
        value={this.state.age}
        onChange={this.onhandleChange}
        name="tenant"
        displayEmpty
        className={classes.selectEmpty}
      >
        <MenuItem value="" disabled>
          Choose Option
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="a">A</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="b">B</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="c">C</MenuItem>
      </Select>
      <FormHelperText>Tenant</FormHelperText>
    </FormControl>
      </div>

      <Button
        type="reset"
        fullWidth
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        className={classes.submit}
      >
        Reset
      </Button>

      <Button
        type="submit"
        fullWidth
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        className={classes.submit}
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </form>
```

Do I need to compulsorily use refs? is this a better approach? or using 
   states is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by set the inital state into variable then reset it like this

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    static initialState = {
       // your object state
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        //set your state here when init component
        this.state = {
        }
    }

    resetForm() {
        this.setState(initialState)
    }
}
```

Let me know if you still have problem